# SAX Parser Exceprtion

Tags: android

When I run my application the following error will occur sometimes, but only sometimes. Can you explain why it occurs only occasionally and what the solution for this is?

The error message is:

```
03-13 14:38:18.055: WARN/System.err(1866): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: '>' actual: '?' (position:END_TAG </Curre>@137:35 in java.io.StringReader@438e0ef0) 
03-13 14:38:18.064: WARN/System.err(1866):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:151)
03-13 14:38:18.074: WARN/System.err(1866):     at com.fitzengineering.teslaworldnet.interfacelayer.ParseXMLString.convertPeoples(ParseXMLString.java:484)
03-13 14:38:18.074: WARN/System.err(1866):     at com.fitzengineering.teslaworldnet.presentationlayer.People.onCreate(People.java:91)
03-13 14:38:18.074: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
03-13 14:38:18.084: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
03-13 14:38:18.095: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
03-13 14:38:18.104: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)03-13 14:38:18.104: WARN/System.err(1866): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
03-13 14:38:18.114: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 14:38:18.124: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-13 14:38:18.134: WARN/System.err(1866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
03-13 14:38:18.134: WARN/System.err(1866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 14:38:18.144: WARN/System.err(1866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-13 14:38:18.144: WARN/System.err(1866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
03-13 14:38:18.154: WARN/System.err(1866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
03-13 14:38:18.154: WARN/System.err(1866):
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As it seams your document varies and sometimes is not well formed so it can't be parsed. Could you post the doc that causes the exception?

Comment: may i know how i send the dovument to.When copy the total java and copy in Add Comment box it shows more characters.So,tell me how can i post that docuent to u.Thanks